# Which function is the last function when powering off?

Tags: kernel, boot

I trace the code and got:

```
native_machine_shutdown()
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L682

but I didn't see any code to shut down the power supply or trigger which CPU register to power down?

I got there from:

```
void kernel_power_off(void)
{
    kernel_shutdown_prepare(SYSTEM_POWER_OFF);
    if (pm_power_off_prepare)
        pm_power_off_prepare();
    migrate_to_reboot_cpu();
    syscore_shutdown();
    pr_emerg("Power down\n");
    kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_SHUTDOWN);
    machine_power_off();
}
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/reboot.c#L287

Comment: I guess this is x86_64 specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `reboot.c`, and nicely commented.

```
static void native_machine_power_off(void)
{
    if (pm_power_off) {
        if (!reboot_force)
            machine_shutdown();
        pm_power_off();
    }
    /* A fallback in case there is no PM info available */
    tboot_shutdown(TB_SHUTDOWN_HALT);
}
```

So, `pm_power_off`: That now is *really* platform-specific; it's different whether you're on a gaming console or a rack server.

You're probably looking for the EFI driver that does this:

```
efi.reset_system(EFI_RESET_SHUTDOWN, EFI_SUCCESS, 0, NULL);
```

in drivers/firmware/efi/reboot.c

Comment: 1. In general, reboot_force should be false, so machine_shutdown() will be called, then it calls native_machine_shutdown() as issue described, but it seems no PSU shutdown or CPU shutdown in native_machine_shutdown() 2. Can't find function content of pm_power_off(), is that from BIOS?

Comment: `pm_power_off` is, as said, something hardware-specific, and your kernel lets that point to an implementation that fits your hardware. I specifically pointed out the implementation you're looking for is in drivers/firmware/efi/reboot.c.